# How to use angular build assets inside python flask static?

Tags: python, angular, flask

I am working on application which uses angular7 in the front end and python flask framework in the back end. I m trying to take the angular build i.e., dist folder and configuring in flask as per the flask structure.

I am not able to load the images in this server. where images path in the dist is like `dist/assets/images`.

```
flask
---app.py
---templates
   ----index.html
---static
   ---- main6gaugsx.js
   ---- runtime7gyg.js
--conf files
```

I tried to move the these images inside the static folder of flask.  But  I cannot set the path of images in `main6gaugsx.js`, since it is bundled code. Also images may increase later point of time. I cant do this changes every time of deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue as well and here is the solution that I came up with:

1. Put your project images into a folder `static`, so that each time you add an image in your code, it looks like this:

   ```
    <img src="static/any/path/to/img.jpg">
   ```

   For example, my project looks like that: [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcJ3y.png)
   (this is an ugly work-around and maybe there is a better way to "translate" the source path on build, please let me know if you find any)

2. When building your app, specify the [--deploy-url](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url) flag. This will add the prefix to all the src and href properties in the generated `index.html`:

   ```
   ng build --configuration production --deploy-url static/
   ```
3. Put all the files except for index.html from the generated dist directory into the `static` directory of your flask project. Also putt your images here according to how they are organised in your angular project (`static/assets/img` for me)
4. Put your index.html file into `templates` directory of your flask app. I put it into `templates/ng_app/index.html`.
5. Call your angular page like that:

```
@app.route('/ng-app')
def browsertest():
   return render_template('ng_app/index.html')
```

The good point of this solution is that you don't have to change static or template directories. I needed to keep them the way they were because I was integrating a new ng app into an existing flask app and didn't want to touch anything that was built by other developers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not move the files manually, it will only complicate the deployment process and be the place of many issues in the future.
2. Try an set your AngularJS output build directory to be the static folder of the Flask application. Usually it is in the webpack configuration. This will ensure that you are not managing the frontend build files manually and also ensure the relative paths in the JS and CSS files would all be preserved.

But the issue would be `index.html` will also be placed in the `static` folder and not in the templates folder. To deal with that, set your `template_folder` during Flask `app` creation to `static/build` or wherever the `index.html` is being placed in the `static` folder.

```
# assuming, the angular build is in the statis/build directory
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='static/build`)
```

Comment: @Arunmozhi my build tends to lump the index.html into the same directory as all the other static assets.  Unfortunately setting flask to use the same value for static_folder and template_folder causes the index.html file to be loaded fine, but all other assets to throw a 404

Answer (score 0):

I changed angular build outputPath to point to static folder.

```
    "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "my-project/dist/static",// changes
      "index": "src/index.html",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
       "assets": [
         "src/assets",
         "src/favicon.ico"
      ],
    },
.
.

    },
```

moved build static folder inside service file and updated the static_folder and template_folder path in main.py as below.

```
    cp -r angular/my-project/dist/static service/app
```

in main.py.

```
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='static')

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
     return render_template('index.html')
```